# SharePoint Workflow 2013 doesn't run

Tags: workflow, manager

Good day!
I have SharePoint Farm 2016 installed on computer without Internet Connection. 
For this computer I installed Workflow Manager 1.0.
The step «Add host to Workflow Farm» failed, but previous steps were successful.
I added host to Workflow Manager Farm after ServiceBus-KB2799752-x64-EN installation. 
Then I executed the following PowerShell commands:

```
Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://MySiteURL" -WorkflowHostUri ' https://MySiteURL:12290' -AllowOAuthHttp -Force

Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://MySiteURL" -WorkflowHostUri ' https://MySiteURL:12291' -AllowOAuthHttp –Force
```

In SharePoint Designer I can create and public SharePoint Workflow 2013. But when I try to run my workflow, I get this error:
«Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page and then start the workflow»

I executed WorkflowMgmtPool recycle and restarted the WorkflowServiceBackend Service like here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193529(v=azure.10).aspx

No results.
I checked the status of all Workflow and Service Bus services. They all was running. I restarted them.
I installed WorkflowManager-KB3104066-x64-EN and restarted machine. No results.
I opened Central Administration site and checked the status of "Workflow Service Application Proxy". Workflow Service is connected.
But I can’t understand why I can’t run Workflow 2013.
I looked this
 https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/05a4bcda-f576-4054-a569-e0feb5cf5510/workflow-showing-error-when-i-click-to-start-something-went-wrong-to-try-again-reload-the-page?forum=sharepointadmin
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/48079.sharepoint-2013-something-went-wrong-to-try-again-reload-the-page-and-then-start-the-workflow.aspx
http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/Troubleshooting-Publishing-and-Executing-Workflows-in-SP2013-Beta-2
But it didn’t help. How to fix this problem?

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Good day,
I enabled claim-based authentication for my site collection and workflow 2013 works. The topic about this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/e504e159-2f79-4cc4-885a-d1e74250a09a/convertspwebapplication-new-parameter-from?forum=sharepointadmin
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/convert-spwebapplication?view=sharepoint-ps
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configure-authentication-providers-ae1b4709-e04b-4870-aee8-8a60a0fa787c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

And Workflow Manager 1.0 must be installed by account which runs SP services.